# WCF - error Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message

Tags: wcf, binding, soapui, saml-2.0

I am trying to cal WCF service using SOAP UI and get the following error; not sure what is the wrong.
        error:Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.

```
    web.config
             <system.serviceModel>
            <diagnostics performanceCounters="All">
              <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
              <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" messageFlowTracing="true"/>
            </diagnostics>
            <behaviors>
              <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
                  <!--<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="200" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>-->
                  <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always"/>
                  <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                    <issuedTokenAuthentication audienceUriMode="BearerKeyOnly" certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"
                                    trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" allowUntrustedRsaIssuers="false"></issuedTokenAuthentication>
                  </serviceCredentials>
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
            <bindings>
              <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsFedBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                            maxReceivedMessageSize="262144" maxBufferPoolSize="262144">
                  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384" maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="262144" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message issuedKeyType="BearerKey" issuedTokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0"
                                    negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
                  </security>
                  <security mode="None">
                    <!--<message  negotiateServiceCredential="true"></message>-->
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
              <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpClientServiceBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                            maxReceivedMessageSize="262144" maxBufferPoolSize="262144">
                  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384" maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="262144" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                  <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </wsHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <services>
              <service name="XXX.Service" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
                <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="https://ws40022517..intranet/XXXX.Service/" />
                  </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsFedBinding"
                            contract="XXX.Contract.Vault.ServiceContract.IVaultService"/>
              </service>
            </services>

          </system.serviceModel>
          <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

            <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
            <httpProtocol>
              <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
              </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
          </system.webServer>
          <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000" newVersion="3.3.1.4000"/>
              </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
          </runtime>
          <system.identityModel>
            <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
              <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <trustedIssuers>
                  <add thumbprint="XXXXC" name="SignCertificate"/>
                </trustedIssuers>
              </issuerNameRegistry>
              <securityTokenHandlers>
                <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
                <add type="XXXX.OcdSaml2SecurityTokenHandler, XXX.WCFExtension"/>
              </securityTokenHandlers>
              <claimsAuthenticationManager type="XXXX.Security.SoapClaimsAuthenticationManager, XXXX"/>
            </identityConfiguration>
          </system.identityModel>

If I comment the TranportwithMessagesecurity and add just transport and none then it shows that channel endpoint not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in webconfig and try it:

```
  <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
      authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
      defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDesRsa15"
      includeTimestamp="false"
      messageSecurityVersion="Default" >
  </security>
```

Comment: should this be added under which section?

Comment: its not working under system.webserver; tags are not getting identifued. configuratioin error

Comment: the momment i add the includeTimestamp="false" tag under security which is under federationbinding element service is not getting hosted as the tag is not recognized. not sure if that tag supports under federation binding?

Comment: apparently I dont need the timestamp anymore when I remove that in request it works well as long as the token wrapped under security tag.